# Display apostrophe from <s:property /> Struts

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, struts2

Double single quotes in a struts property tag

I need to display a single apostrophe in a translated string from my properties file. I was using an `<s:text>` tag but this would not allow me add the `escapeJavaScript` parameter. I changed it to an s:property tag and escaped the JavaScript but now the double apostrophes are displayed to the client as just that, two apostrophes.
This text is used in several places where I do use `<s:text>` so I can not simply reduce it to one single apostrophe.

I need to escape JS because for some reason the double apostrophes are breaking the JS of the page.

Does anybody have any idea why using the `<s:property>` appears to escape the double apostrophe rule?

This is my relevant code:

```
  actionMessageShow('<s:property value="%{propf(\'Cannot_load_image\')}" escapeJavaScript="true" escapeHtml="false" />',
  '<s:property value="example.example()"/>');

  Cannot_load_image= L''image example...
```

Comment: "For some reason"? The reason is clear; it renders illegal JavaScript. I don't see any reason to escape your single quotes within the S2 tag itself;  the JSP tags are rendered before your browser ever sees any of the generated JavaScript. Check what the value is after the `propf` call; maybe since you're not running through the text tag the normal escaping isn't applied.

Comment: What do you mean by *breaking the JS of the page*?

Comment: Appears that you messing up Java and JavaScript on the page, even not escaping it properly.